# How to have a remote folder mounted at boot, on system-level?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012-r2, storage, storage-area-network, archive

We use Press Store P5 for backups, running on Windows Server 2012 R2.

One of the folders it sends to tape is mounted remotely via SMB. In order to get the P5 service to see this folder, it has to be mounted on a system level. So far I've been using the method described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553), running the following application on a cmd window:

psexec -i -s net use s: \server\share /persistent:yes

However, I want this done during boot time, so I don't have to remotely login and run it everytime the machine restarts. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the best answer, but I bet you could put that in a scheduled task and select "At Startup" as your trigger timing